# returns null value while counting the results

Tags: php, codeigniter, count

Here is my code for counting the results obtained but the not showing anything on the view page even if it contains value
here is my controller

```
$data['present']= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);
       //var_dump($data['present']);
```

Here is my model

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {


   $temp = explode("-",$date);
   $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
   $this->db->where("YEAR(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[0]);
   $this->db->where("MONTH(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[1]);
   return $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_attendance');
}
```

Here is my view

```
<?php echo $present;?>
```

when i gave `var_dump` to check am getting results like this[image]

Comment: Which line is 540 ?

Comment: line no 540 is `var_dump($data['present']);`

Comment: rename $data in present_report_by_empid .

`$data['present']= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id, $date_);`

Comment: i didnt get what you meaned

Comment: ```$date_ = '2017-02-09';

$data['present']= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id, $date_);

echo $data['present'];```

Comment: Oh . surry . i think date is data .

Comment: with `get_compiled_select` check query : ```public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
{
   $temp = explode("-",$date);

   $this->db->from('tbl_attendance');
   $this->db->where('attendance_status', 1);
   $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
   $this->db->where("YEAR(date_in)",$temp[0]);
   $this->db->where("MONTH(date_in)",$temp[1]);
   return $this->db->get_compiled_select();
}```

Comment: sorry i want my result to be like in the image shown

Comment: I know . Just see the query is correct. with `get_compiled_select `

Answer (score 0):

$present is an array, and you can't echo an array, so you'll have to do a foreach in the view to echo out all the values:

```
<?php foreach($present as $var) {
    echo $var;
<? endforeach ?>
```